# How many triangles can be formed so that the area of $\triangle ABC$ is 9 times $\triangle DEF$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, triangle-inequality

I am currently working on an Olympiad math problem, and I am struggling to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate your help in solving this problem. I was unable to solve the problem because I don't know the exact rules for solving the problem.

**Problem Source**: *Bangladesh Math Olympiad*

*A small hint will be enough for me to proceed.*

> In a triangle, $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B=90^\circ$, and every side has a positive integer-valued length.
> $△DEF$ is inside of $\triangle ABC$ in such a way that $AB\parallel DE$, $BC\parallel EF$, $AC\parallel DF$, and
> the distance between the parallel sides of the triangles are always $2$. How many triangles can be formed so that the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $9$ times  $\triangle DEF$?

Comment: Use similarity of triangles. Common ratio is $3$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its homework problem

Comment: No. It's not a homework problem. I have shown the problem source of this problem. It's the question of BdMO 2016 regional set 1 @Qwerty. so please don't give your opinion as your own will

Comment: @RaihanSarker While it might come from a source other than homework, it is *phrased* like a homework problem.  You have given us a problem statement, with no real indication of any research effort that you have made, nor any indication about what you have done towards solving the problem.  Such questions are not on-topic here.  Please read the [guidelines on context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I revised this answer to make it more of a hint. I'm sorry I did not originally see your "small help" request.

Let the lengths of $\triangle ABC$ be $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $b$ the hypotenuse. For orientation, let $c$ be horizontal and $a$ be vertical, with $A$ and $C$ the opposite angle.

With $\triangle DEF$, there are corresponding sides. How long is $f$? It is $c$, reduced by $2$ on one side, and using similar triangles, reduced by $\frac{2b}{a}+\frac{2c}{a}$ on the other. (In the picture below, the similar triangle ratios to determine that are left as as exercise.)

[image]

So we have one expression for $f$ using subtraction. Meanwhile the two triangles are similar, and with an area ratio of $9$, the legs of the smaller triangle must be $\frac{1}{3}$ as long as of the larger triangle. So you can set up an equation in $a,b,c$ from that.

Next, the big triangle is a Pythagorean triple with $b$ as the hypotenuse, so you can reference the parameterization of such things:

$$\begin{align}
b&=k(m^2+n^2)\\
a&=k(m^2-n^2)\\
c&=2kmn
\end{align}$$

If you combine this with the equation mentioned above, it leads to a conclusion that there are ________ possibilities and you can list them all.

Comment: Rearranging gives $3(a+b+c)=ac$ I arrived at the same by connecting corresponding points and equating the combined area of the resulting trapezoids to eight times the area of the inner triangle.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks, corrected. The extra 2 was omitted later, so it's all good after that.

Comment: I tried so hard but couldn't get the answer. As you got the answer, would you mind solving the full math for me, please? and what the terms m,n, and k are? I couldn't understand clearly... @2'59'2

Comment: @RaihanSarker You can click "edited..." under the answer to see an earlier version that explains in more detail. I do assume familiarity with [Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) which is where the $m,n,k$ come from.

Comment: thank you so much .that was much more effective  @2'59'2